# Assigning variance-covariance matrix in generating artificial data for mixed-effect model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, simulation

I can’t understand specifying correlation between within-participant conditions when generating artificial data for mixed-effect model regression. It would be grateful if you could help me.

My story is here. I would like to make artificial data for reaction time in a behavioral experiment. Log-transformed RT is analyzed by mixed effect model. The model is, in lme4 format, `log(rt) ~ 1 + cond + (1 | participant)`, where `cond` is a within-participant factorial variable with 2 levels: 0 = condition A and 1 = condition B. `participant` represents participant ID. Multiple trials (i.e., items) appears in each condition.

For artificial data, I give the following constraints:

condition A: Mean = 7, SD = 1.5

condition B: Mean = 7.5, SD = 1.8

Because it’s within-participant factorial design, I would like to manipulate correlation between condition A and B. Here, r = 0.2 tentatively.

I followed this blog https://julianquandt.com/post/power-analysis-by-data-simulation-in-r-part-iv/, in particular, the section “Adding a random intercept” in “Building up the random effects structure”. My R code is:

```
set.seed(1)
library(MASS)
library(tidyverse)
library(lmerTest)

# Set parameters ----------------------------------------------
condA_mu <- 7   # exp(7) = 1096.63315843 ms
condA_sd <- 1.5
condB_mu <- 7.5 # exp(7.5) = 1808.04241446 ms
condB_sd <- 1.7
correlation <- 0.2


# Generate dataframe ------------------------------------------
generate_design <- function(n_participants, 
                            n_conditions, 
                            n_items){
   design_matrix <- expand.grid(participant = 1:n_participants, 
                                cond = 1:n_conditions, 
                                item = 1:n_items)
   design_matrix$cond <- ifelse(design_matrix$cond == 1, "A", "B")
   design_matrix$item <- paste0(design_matrix$cond, "_", design_matrix$item) 
   return(design_matrix)
}

data2 <- generate_design(
  n_participants = 50, 
  n_conditions = 2, 
  n_items = 10) 

data2$cond <- ifelse(data2$cond == "A", 0, 1)


# Set parameters ----------------------------------------------
b0 <- condA_mu
b1 <- condB_mu - condA_mu

sigma <- matrix(c(condA_sd^2, 
                  condA_sd*condB_sd*correlation, 
                  condA_sd*condB_sd*correlation, 
                  condB_sd^2), 
                  ncol = 2)

sd_u0   <- sqrt(sigma[1, 2])   #### Question 1 #####
epsilon <- sqrt(sigma[1, 1] - sigma[1, 2]) #### Question 2 #####


# Generate artificial data ------------------------------------
U0 = rnorm(length(unique(data2$participant)), 0, sd_u0) # random intercept

for(i in 1:nrow(data2)){
  data2$rt[i] <- rnorm(1, 
b0+U0[data2$participant[i]]+
    b1*data2$cond[i], 
    epsilon)
}


# Cal correlation ----------------------------------------------
sim_agg_df <- aggregate(log(rt) ~  participant*cond , data2, mean)
cor_df <- spread(sim_agg_df, cond, "log(rt)")
cor(cor_df[,2], cor_df[,3]) #### Question 3 #####


# Fit model -------------------------------------------------------
fit <- lmer(log(rt) ~ 1 + cond + (1 | participant), data = data2)
summary(fit)
```

In the above code, I have three questions.

Question 1: The blog says that covariance (condA_sd*condB_sd*correlation) is given for SD for the random intercept. Why?

Question 2: Here I calculate Epsilon (residuals) by epsilon <- sqrt(sigma[1, 1] - sigma[1, 2]). But I think it is wrong. Instead of sigma[1, 1], is the variance of all data needed?

Question 3: When I calculate the correlation between A and B, I got r = around 0.2 (0.237906 under set.seed(1)) if Nitem = 1 (that is, only single trial per condition). But if Nitem increases, the correlation is not around 0.2, rather, it shows very high value (0.691356 under set.seed(1)). What does happen here?

More variables other than means and SDs  for both conditions and the correlation are needed to generate data?

Thank you very much